# Make a pending transaction to Rinkeby

Tags: rinkeby, pending-transactions

What would be a simple way to generate a transaction that remains pending for a while (on Rinkeby)?

I tried sending to self, adjusting the gas price but that is either confirmed quickly or doesn't show up at all, e.g.:

```
    tx = {
        'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(address, block_identifier='pending'),
        'from': w3.toChecksumAddress(address),
        'to': w3.toChecksumAddress(address),
        'value': 0,
        'gas': 100_000,
        'chainId': w3.eth.chain_id,

        'maxFeePerGas': 300_000_000,
        'maxPriorityFeePerGas': 300_000_000,
    }

    tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key=private_key)
    hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(tx.rawTransaction)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me in the past when it didn't show in Rinkeby as pending, it was because I've sent it with too low a gas price. After raising it I was able to see it as pending. Also, I was using pre-1559 tx type, unlike you. I don't know if it makes a difference.